# Implement a sequence system (trigger flows) that will send notifications based on defined conditions (C#, Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, triggers, architecture

We would like to build a trigger system (trigger flow) that will fire based on some logic for our clients/tenants running system (App, bot, website). For example if the user visited a certain bot flow and did not click on anything the system should trigger a follow up notification after 15 minutes of inactivity.

**Things that change:**

- The time to wait until the condition is met is configurable for each trigger flow (15 minutes, 50 minutes, 10 minutes).
- More than one trigger flow will be configured for each tenant.
- New users are assigned every day and thus the system should be able to scale to check for all of them (10 new user every day)

We are using c# and Asp.net core and hosted our projects on cloud, we thought of having an azure function that will fire every minute and do the check for each trigger by querying the database (calculate the time since last activity, and do some dynamic logic) and send the notification if conditions match.

But we don't think this architecture will scale as if we have 50 triggers and 400,000 user then we would query the database 50 times in a minute to do the checks for all the users and we think this will overkill the database

Any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to end up fairly messy if you do it server-side.  You are trying to build a generic solution here, when you really don't have that many different event types, and the specific client-side solution is quite straightforward.

Send your "timeout" to the client, and in javascript reset a time variable on every click/key-press/etc, ontimeout, when the timeout fires, compare since the last action, and if it's timed-out, send an event out.

This is really hard server-side.  You have to do things like distinguish between a user closing their browser/app and a user sitting idle... that gets ugly, and really expensive.

Comment: I think i need to rephrase my question a bit, its not limited to frontend system only,  and we want to use the system for other things like for example a messenger bot where users interact with it and if they abandoned a special flow, the system will send a notification after for example 15 minutes

Comment: Once again, detecting things that are not happening is inherently expensive, and is best done as close to the event as possible.  If your messenger bot instance does not receive input for 15 minutes, have it send an "idle event" and have that trigger your flow.

Comment: Interesting, but what if we don't control frontend as we don't control the messenger bot, its working through Facebook and we have to check inactivity from the backend. If we do check inactivity manually then we would have to check the current status of all users always. I'm I missing something?

Comment: Then you will need to do the ugly/expensive thing.  As a recommendation, for a situation like this, create a process that "ages" all of the conversations at once, and marks them as "expired" when they have hit their timeout, not one per user.  That should help with your scaling issue.